# Changing Text using Photoshop API in UXP Developer

Tags: javascript

I am looking to build a Photoshop plugin which changes the text contents inside a text layer in my photoshop document.

I have the plugin set up correctly, and have it appearing. I have also managed to get the plugin to find the layer I want and fetch the text but when I go to change the text, I get the below error.

This is the code I currently have:

```
function changeLayerText() {
    const app = require("photoshop").app;

    var layers = app.activeDocument.layers;

    //Find the layer I want to change the text in
    var firstLayer = layers.getByName("bat3_name");

    //Store the new text, and set the contents of the firstLayer to newText
    var newText = "AN Other";
    firstLayer.textItem.contents = newText;

}

document.getElementById("changeText").addEventListener("click", changeLayerText);
```

This is the error I am currently getting. I know I need to use the executeAsModal to make changes to the document, but not sure how I implement it.

```
saveDocumentSelection may modify the state of Photoshop. Such events are only allowed from inside a modal scope. See https://www.adobe.com/go/ps_executeasmodal for details.
```

Any suggestions would be very helpful.